# Obtener URL local del cliente

Tags: php, javascript, html, windows

Tengo un `INPUT FILE`, lo que necesito es obtener el `PATH` local de dicho fichero, Ej: '*G:/fichero/fichero.pdf*'
Obviamente por razones de seguridad esto por defecto no es posible, pero me gustaría saber si existe alguna configuración del navegador o extensión de chrome para que esto funcione.

Lo pregunto porque hay una extensión de chrome para abrir un fichero local del cliente desde una web, por lo que puede que también haya una solución para este problema

Recalcar que el cliente del que se va a obtener el `PATH` local es de confianza

Answer (score 2):

No, no es posible.

> Los *scripts* corren en un entorno cerrado donde solo pueden ejecutar tareas relacionadas con la web y no tareas de propósito como crear ficheros. <sup>[[1]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaScript#Security)</sup>

---

> Hay especificaciones en JavaScript *standard* que restringen ciertas funcionalidades, como por ejemplo el acceso a ficheros locales. <sup>[[2]](https://www.us-cert.gov/publications/securing-your-web-browser)</sup>

---

> [...] porque el *file system* está contextualizado, una aplicación web no puede acceder a ficheros de otras aplicaciones. Tampoco puedes leer or escribir ficheros a un directorio arbitrario en el disco duro del cliente. [[3]](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File_System_API/Introduction#restrictions)

---

Después de estas citas, prosigo.

Algo que se suele hacer para conseguir lo que pretendes es servir* un servicio de escritorio des de la web, que **el usuario deberá descargar e instalar**.
Este servicio de escritorio instalado en el lado del *client* actuaría como *server* para que la web acceda al *file system* mediante llamadas (ya sean HTTP, tipo *webhook*, ...).

* La aplicación web hospeda un instalable para cada sistema operativo (*RPM* para Linux, *MSI* para Windows, ...) o un comprimido.

Tampoco es algo inmediato, porque debes trazar un mapa de IPs de todos los usuarios para que la web, centralizada, sepa dónde tiene que enviar las peticiones.
Al resultar algo más complicado, lo más normal siempre es instalar directamente un servicio que sirve una aplicación web local. Funciona con la misma mecánica, pero no hay que pelearse con los *CORS* ni con la complejidad *multi-server*.

Espero que sirva.